# Requests giving errors while importing Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.4

When I am trying to import requests in python 3.4.2, it gives me the following errors:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
ImportError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
ImportError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package
```

I am not trying to use any files like email.parser, yet it shows an error. How can I fix this? I have tried to install requests again, for instance, with `sudo pip3.4 install requests` and `sudo pip3.4 install --upgrade requests`. Note: I am running macOS Sierra.

Comment: You probably have a local file called email.py which is shadowing the standard library module. Rename your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you leave it an an answer, I'll accept it @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a local file called email.py which is shadowing the standard library module. Rename your file.